# Can we use tracking handle to the value class?

Tags: c++-cli

Using c++ CLI, is it recommended not to use tracking handle for value class?

for example

```
value class Point {
};
```

Point p; 
or Point ^p;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++/CLI permits that syntax, unfortunately, it cannot be expressed directly in other managed languages.  You end up with the value getting boxed in an object and stored on the GC heap.  Every assignment will box, reading the value unboxes it again.  That's quite expensive and 99.9% of the time is the wrong thing to do.  The point of value types is to make your code *fast*, avoiding the extra indirection through an object reference and taking advantage of processor registers.  A value type value like Point fits in two registers.

By declaring it as a handle, you get the disadvantage of a `ref class` but *add* the expense of having to unbox the value every time you retrieve a member of the value type.  It therefore makes no sense to do this at all, if you need a Point class with reference type semantics then just declare a `ref class Point` and entirely avoid the un/boxing cost.  C++/CLI has a few design flaws, induced by trying make it match native C++ semantics.  This is one of them.

So no, this is not recommended.